# Where can I post opinionated questions?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Stack Overflow isn't the place to ask opinionated programming questions. It appears that programmers.stackexchange isn't the right place either. If I have an opinion based question related to programming, programming concepts and things of that nature, where shall I post them?

Comment: On some other forum.

Comment: *We're not a forum.*

Comment: Reddit, Hacker News, Twitter, Facebook, Yahoo! Answers... there are plenty of places to ask opinion based questions.

Comment: I figured a lot of top-notch programmers gather around the StackExchange regions. You would think there would be a section where we can discuss high level programming opinions.

Comment: @John, what does "high-level" have to do with "opinions"?

Comment: Top-notch programmers continue to gather around Stack Exchange *because* we don't waste their time with endless opinion-based questions.

Comment: "Which is better, JavaScript or Java?"  `</ducks>`

Comment: @John _"... where we can discuss high level programming opinions ..."_ If you're thinking about _high level_ regarding software architecture and frameworks, you might be better off, asking questions about software architecture issues at [SE Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Terminology aside, I'm guessing that there would be a section where we can discuss opinionated programming matters. I guess not.

Comment: The problem to me is not being able to ask questions that might get opinionated answers about patterns, concepts, and best practices. It's not about starting some dumb fight about "tabs or spaces".

Answer (score 13):

Elsewhere. Or in chat.

There's no room for those questions on any Stack Exchange site.

Comment: Elsewhere includes in chat :), so word order should be: "In chat. Or elsewhere."

Comment: @nicael, that would not be the same thing. As you mentioned, technically `chat` is a subset of `elsewhere` unless we clarify by mentioning `chat` first. However, not doing that results in `chat` being singled out from `elsewhere`, in a similar way to [My Friends... and Zoidberg](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/MyFriendsAndZoidberg), which may well be intentional (and had me chuckle in my beard for awhile).