# Is there an alternative forum for discussion questions on Meta Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, forums

On Meta, a lot of reponses are in comments and this is not the case on other Stack Exchange Q&A sites. Why?

Personally, I think that the main reason is that questions posted on Meta are not IT/technical questions that are well treated using the concept of Q&A but are human questions that need exchanges and that sometimes have no answer.

Since Meta Stack Overflow is not a good site to post questions, is there another site with forum style that can be used for that?

Comment: I have tried to clarify what you're asking, but what is the *problem* you see? Yes there are generally more comments per post on Metas than mains, but is that bad (or even unexpected)?

Comment: You can try chat?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where can I post opinionated questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278500/where-can-i-post-opinionated-questions)

Comment: @gnat I'm not thrilled by that dupe as this question specifically asks about Meta which has by definition some opinionated questions that require (threaded) discussion.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: thanks for your english correction. My problem is that I find that Q&A style is not appropriated for all types of questions and that it would be interesting to have another solution as forum. I find that particulary true for Meta Stack Overflow. It is only a suggestion to try to improve this site.

Comment: @gnat: I don't find that my question is duplicate. I have follow your link and the question is similar but with other terms. I want to add that your link is an example of what I write. The first comment are in reality 3 answers !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> On META, a lot of reponses are in comment below post and this is not the case on other StackExchange Q&A sites.
>
> Why ?

Probably because it usually needs more efforts in clarification of questions coming up here.

> Personally, I think that the main reason is that questions posted on Meta are not IT/technical questions that are well treated using the concept of Q&A but are human questions that need exchanges and that sometimes have no answer.

I think most cases of questions and even specific ones are likely already asked and answered here or in the FAQ.

> Since Meta Stack Overflow is not a good site to post questions, is there another site with forum style that can be used for that?

Stack Exchange sites aren't meant to be *forum style*, none of them.